# Drawing a Thick, Arched Line in Android

Tags: android, canvas, view, drawing, geometric-arc

Greetings Everyone.

I was wondering how would I go about drawing an ached line on a canvas.  If I were to continue this line it would make a perfect circle.  I've got pie wedges which is close but I just want the outside of the wedge and it needs to be circular.  What should I do

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html and the drawArc function

  EDIT: sorry, the link to the function can't be parsed properly by so, I am posting the class only as a link

Comment: @apps You should post these kind of things as answers, not comments.  That way others know the question has already been answered.  Comments are reserved for asking clarifying questions, asides, etc.

Comment: @Mayra thanks for this information, I am quite new and just check the website from time to time, I saw several questions with answers in the form of comments, and I thought that it is ok for "short and straightforward" answers. I guess I have to read the SO rules if I decide to spend more time in it, sorry if I broke the rules

Comment: @apps No worries, I don't think its a hard and fast rule... people do it sometimes if they just want to post a link and not do a full answer.  Its just that if it is the full answer, then the question never gets an official answer and it looks like it is still need of one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and the `drawArc()` function.

Comment: I tried that but it draws the whole wedge.  I just want an outline kind of thing.  Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: useCenter false (javadoc: If true, include the center of the oval in the arc, and close it if it is being stroked. This will draw a wedge). If it is false, you have only 2 points and you can't make a shape, if true you have 3 points to connect, and they are "filled"

Comment: Ok, after changing that, I think the best way to describe what it draws is as follows.
1)Find The Two Points
2)Connect the points
3)Draw Arc Between Points
4)Fill in the resulting shape.

Comment: I had this somewhere in a project, the problem is that I don't know where is the project, and I forgot it. You have to play with the dimensions of the RectF oval, but I can't give you a ready-to-use code

Comment: Like making a long oval, and using the center as a 3rd point to draw, or something like that, draw it down on a list of paper and you will see how it should look like

Comment: I understand exactly why it's doing what it's doing.  But I really just need a think curved line.

Comment: Found The answer!  I needed this:   ring.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
ring.setStrokeWidth(50);

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do it, since I did it with the rect, but I guess you can just draw the arc, and another one on top of it which is 1 px smaller to cover the first one, which sounds like an awful solution, sorry that I didn't hekp

Comment: Now all I need to do is figue out ho to draw it to the center of the screen.

Comment: cool, but why 50, is it a "donut" that you wanted to make the whole time :)

Comment: now you really lost me with the "center of the screen", anyway, glad that you solved it (whatever it was that you wanted after all :))

Comment: double lol, I thought that "thick" is like "thin" , I saw now that it is actually like fat! poor English sucks :)

Comment: How would I center a RectF in the middle of the canvas?

Comment: Hm, I guess you can just subtract the width of the rect from the width of the canvas, and offset the rect with that many pixels (rect.offset()) , then the same for the height  EDIT: offset with 1/2 of these of course

Comment: you can post an answer to your question, I think you can accept your own question