# How to draw an arc with varying thickness

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to draw an arc in android with varying thickness, as represented in the below image,

[image: Arc from from some startDegree to endDegree with varying thickness]

Is it possible to draw an arc and clip it? as the arc can be between any degrees (startDegree to endDegree), i can't acheive this with path.

so my requirement is something like this,

[image: example code snippet]

Please help me to achieve the above.

Comment: this **might** help:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4200799/3436942

Comment: @jbutler483, I can draw an arc with the following code snippet `canvas.drawArc(rectangleF,startDegree, endDegree, false, paint);`but the arc is with same thickness, i need that to be with different start and end thickness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can do this using [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

You arc has edges like:

- horizontal straight line
- upper arc
- vertical straight line
- lower arc

So, you need to take some math to calculate these coordinates and params.

**UPD:**
Please, take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982354/equation-of-a-specific-shapes-edge/982431#982431)
Seems like I found exact formula for this curve there.

**UPD 2:**
About how to draw spiral on canvas, I think not very bad solution is do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824391/drawing-a-spiral-on-an-html-canvas-using-javascript) (there javascript is used, but it doesn't matter – the idea is the same).
The only thing: it is needed to write spiral equation in Cartesian coordinate system. Try to do this by yourself. If you fail, then ask me.

**UPD 3:**
Check mentioned above question's UPD2 section to find Cartesian coordinate system parametrization.
It might contain mistakes, I didn't check it by myself, but the idea should be clear.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, i can draw two lines either horizontal or vertical (based on angle), and an arc(upper arc). but i can't draw lower arc because of two problems, 1.centre point for lower arc should be different based on angle,  2.The maximum thickness of the arc should reach only at the end.

Comment: i guess, it can be achieved by, the upper arc with constant radius, and the arc with variable (decreasing) radii, in other words, the inner can should be like a spiral.

Comment: I asked this question on math.stackexchange.com: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982354/equation-of-a-specific-shapes-edge
This is an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral, so everything you should do is to find spiral's parameters and check whether it suits you :)

Answer (score 0):

The following function would work, keeping in mind the angle in degrees for converting into radians. Kindly change the datatype to double:

```
void spiralArc(int startAngle, ind endAngle, int centreX, int centreY,int radius, int maxThickness)
{
    int iRadius;
    for(int ang=startAngle;ang<=endAngle;ang++)
    {
        iRadius = radius - (int)((double) maxThickness*(double)ang/(double)endAngle);
        drawLine(centreX+(radius*cos(ang)), centreY+(radius*sin(ang)), centreX+(iradius*cos(ang)), centreY+(iradius*sin(ang)))
    }
}
```